# Create User To Run SQL Migration Script Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure

Currently moving a database to Azure SQL. I've generated a script to import the database. In SQL management studio, I've connected to the cloud database as the server admin. I try to run the script - though I get multiple errors such as -

ODBC error: State: 28000: Error: 18456 Message:'[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user '##MS_InstanceCertificate##'.'.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 3, Line 11

and

Looking around I found; 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins

I went through the steps to create a user and add to the role dbmanager. 
I'm still getting the same errors when running the database import script.

As a heads up, I've run this script logged in as the server admin and as the user created by the server admin.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you find solution for this? I have the same problem and I couldn't find a solution

Comment: Any solution to this, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a bit misleading, it hasn't (necessarily) something to do with certificates. In general, this error message says that connecting to the database with a certain user failed. So check...

- if the user exists
- if the username is spelled correctly
- if the database you connect to exists
- if the database name is spelled correctly